# replace multiple <br> in javascript replace with single <br>?

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I want to replace the multiple `<br>` tags with single `<br>` in a text.

my text like,

```
<p>fhgfhgfhgfh</p>
<br><br>
<p>ghgfhfgh</p>
<br><br>
<p>fghfghfgh</p>
<br><br>
<p>fghfghfgh</p>
<br><br>
<p>fghfgh</p>
<br><br>
```

How i replace the multiple `<br>` with single `<br>`?.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this

```
var str="<p>fhgfhgfhgfh</p><br><br><p>ghgfhfgh</p><br><br><p>";

var n=str.replace(/<br><br>/g,"<br>");

console.log(n);
```

Working [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Hw32q/)

**Edit**: Above works for 2 `br` tags, code below should take care of any number of **br** tags.

```
var n = str.replace(/(<br>)+/g, '<br>');
```

Working [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Hw32q/2/)

where `/.../` denotes a regular expression, `(<br>)` denotes `<br>` tag, and `+` denotes  one or more occurrence of the previous expression and finally `g` is for global replacement.

Answer (score 5):

This should do the trick:

```
str.replace(/(?:<br>){2,}/g, '<br>')
```

Or, if they can be on different lines:

```
str.replace(/(?:<br>\s*){2,}/g, '<br>')
```