# replace multiple break tags with single and respect text between breaks

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I want to replace the multiple breaks with a single break in the body and it should respect text between breaks. Also it shouldn't affect the event handlers on any element.
For example,

```
text1<br/><br/><br/>text2<br/><br/><p>text3</p>text4<br/><br/><br/>text5
```

should change to

```
text1<br/>text2<br/><p>text3</p>text4</p><br/>text5
```

I founds some questions related to this on stackoverflow but I couldn't able to make those work for my scenario. I believe it's not duplicate so posting it.

Comment: Could you tell us which solutions from other questions that you have tried but did not work for you?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13699995/replace-multiple-br-in-javascript-replace-with-single-br

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var oldText="text1<br/><br/><br/>text2<br/><br/><p>text3</p>text4<br/><br/><br/>text5";
var newText = oldText.replace(/(?:<br[^>]*>\s*){2,}/g, '<br>');
```

**EDIT**

As per your need

```
$("#clickableDiv" ).click(function() {
        alert('clicked me');
    });

    $("p" ).click(function() {
        alert('clicked me');
    });

    var bodyHTML = $('body').html();
    console.log( "ready!" );

    bodyHTML = bodyHTML.replace(/(?:<br[^>]*>\s*){2,}/g,"<br/>");
    console.log(bodyHTML);
    $('body').html(bodyHTML);
});
```

[UPDATED FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/v4vishnuprasad/q6syj61k/1/)

Comment: I need to replace in entire document, will your solution have impact on event handlers?

Comment: hav u tried this code. or give full code so that we can check it?

Comment: It's removing event handlers. It works only if the replace code executes before registering events on elements. code: https://jsfiddle.net/chaitut715/q6syj61k/

Answer (score 0):

Just try

```
$a = "text1<br/><br/><br/>text2<br/><br/><p>text3</p>text4<br/><br/><br/>text5";
$b = preg_replace("/(?:<br\/>)+/", "<br/>", $a);
// $b == "text1<br/>text2<br/><p>text3</p>text4<br/>text5"
```